# Problema na renderização de mapa usando os pacotes Leaflet e Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, mapas, leaflet, flexdashboard

Caros,

Não estou conseguindo renderizar um pequeno mapinha numa Dashboard que estou construindo usando Flexdashboard.

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem: Error: método não aplicável para 'metaData' aplicado a um objeto de classe "c('double', 'numeric')"

Não consegui entender o problema e não localizei informações... alguém teria alguma sugestão?

```
renderLeaflet({
    
leaflet() %>%
  # chamando o mapa base 
  addTiles() 

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  # plotando os pontos no mapa 
  addCircleMarkers(data = cursos, lat = ~latitude, 
                   lng = ~longitude, radius = ~3)
})

# criando uma coluna na tabela de dados com 
# os dados que serão mostrados na janela popup
# mapa_cursos <- cursos %>% 
#   mutate(popup_info = paste ("Nome do curso", nome.curso, "<br/>", 
#                              "Realizado em:", ano, "<br/>", "Cidade", 
#                              municipio, "<br/>", "Estado", UF, "<br/>", 
#                              "Modalidade", modalidade, "<br/>", "Duração",
#                              duracao.dias, "<br/>", "Carga Horária", 
#                              carga.horaria)) 


# inserindo a janela popup no código
# leaflet() %>% 
#   addTiles() %>% 
#   addCircleMarkers(data=mapa_cursos, lat = ~latitude, 
#                    lng = ~longitude, radius = ~3, popup = ~popup_info)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Além do que pediu o Marcus, avalie a necessidade de manter aqueles blocos de código que estão comentados na pergunta. Quanto mais precisa for a pergunta, mais fácil de identificarmos o problema e ajudarmos.

Comment: Parece que o problema (a julgar pela mensagem de erro) está quando você chama `metaData`.

Comment: Caros, consegui identificar meu problema... como juntei partes de 2 scripts distintos, não percebi e acabei inserindo no meu código dois objetos com o mesmo nome, de forma que o conteúdo do "segundo" subscreveu o conteúdo o "primeiro"... razão pela qual as colunas "latitude" e "longitude" do meu data.frame original não eram encontradas no segundo objeto para serem plotadas. De qualquer forma, agradeço pela atenção e pelas orientações. Da próxima vez encaminharei a pergunta da forma correta. Abs!